# Realm not saving (or possibly not returning) String values of related object

Tags: android, realm

Realm not saving (or possibly not returning) String values of related object...

i have 3 models:

```
public class Customer extends RealmObject {
@Expose
@PrimaryKey
private Long id;
@Expose
private Long historicalId;
@Expose
private String versionUUID;
@Expose
private String nameCompany;
@Expose
private String email;
@Expose
private String phoneNumber;
@Expose
private String notes;
@Expose
private boolean active;
@Expose
private boolean currentVersion;
@Expose
private Date lastUpdated;
@Expose
private Date dateCreated;

public Customer() {
}
```

and

```
public class Project extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private Long id;
private Long historicalId;
private String versionUUID;
private String name;
private String description;
private String addressLineOne;
private String addressLineTwo;
private String addressCity;
private String addressState;
private String addressZip;
private String notes;
private Date lastUpdated;
private Date dateCreated;
private boolean active;
private boolean currentVersion;
private Customer customer;
private String customerVersion;

public Project() {
}
```

and lastly (added for the comment question)

```
public class Receipt extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;
private String vendor;
private Double amount;
private String description;
private Date dateCreated;
private Date lastUpdated;
private Date dateSynced;
private byte[] imageByteArray;
private Project project;
private String projectVersion;
private int imgWidht;
private int imgHeight;

public Receipt() {
}
```

i am saving the data via:

```
    public static void syncAllDataToRealm(Context context){
    Globals globals = Globals.getInstance();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(globals.getAllCustomers());
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(globals.getAllProjects());
    realm.commitTransaction();
    testRealCommit(context);
}
```

and i am verifying the data via

```
    private static void testRealCommit(Context context){
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    RealmQuery<Customer> customerRealmQuery = realm.where(Customer.class);
    RealmResults<Customer> customerRealmResults = customerRealmQuery.findAll();
    logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, "===== CUSTOMER ======= "));
    for(Customer c: customerRealmResults){
        logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, c.getId() + " - " + c.getNameCompany()));
    }
    logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, "===== CUSTOMER  GLOBAL======= "));
    for(Customer c: Globals.getInstance().getAllCustomers()){
        logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, c.getId() + " - " + c.getNameCompany()));
    }


    RealmQuery<Project> projectRealmQuery = realm.where(Project.class);
    RealmResults<Project> projectRealmResults = projectRealmQuery.findAll();
    logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, "===== PROJECT ======="));
    for(Project p: projectRealmResults){
        logger.debug(LogUtility.generateMessage(TAG, p.getId() + " - " + p.getName()));
    }
}
```

for some reason:

```
c.getNameCompany()
```

returns a null in the above code... if i dont add the project data to realm it works fine....

realm is bein set up in my Application file via:

```
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .name("receiptbucket.realm")
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

any ideas???

found out something else... if i swap the commit order, adding all customers after adding all projects it works

```
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(globals.getAllProjects());
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(globals.getAllCustomers());
```

short term fix but i would like to know why i have to do it this way for the customer data to stick...

(New Issue)

now when i call copyOrUpdate for the Receipt it wipes all the customer data Projects Customer....

Comment: what do you mean "if i dont add the project data to realm it works fine" ?

Comment: if i dont add the product data via copyorupdate, the company data goes in fine... No Null company names...  Its really bizzarre..\

Answer (score 1):

From your last description, I think the problem is the `Project` list returned by `globals.getAllProjects()` contains some `Customer` which has `null` value for `nameCompany` .

The reason is your `Customer` class has an `id` which is annotated with `@PrimaryKey`, when `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(globals.getAllProjects())` called, Realm will create or **update** related objects recursively. (That is the whole point of **update** here).

If it finds a customer which has the same `id` and already saved in the Realm, it will just use all new values from `Project.customer` to update the one existed in the Realm. If the `Procject.customer.nameCompany` is null, you will have the problem you described above.

The solution would be make the `globals.getAllProjects()` return the latest value you want to update, since there is no way for Realm to understand whether the `null` values are something you want to ignore or update to.

Comment: Sadly all my customer data is coming across with companyName info...  I tested that both server and client side....  if project has some null strings could this bork it??

Comment: ok. so now i am seeing the original error when i save a Receipt object which references Project... It nulls out all the attached Customer data...  I will add the Customer model to the above issue...

Answer (score 0):

i was able to overcome the last error by querying realm and reattaching the Customer that was getting nulled out to the Project which is part of the Receipt....

so then i started playing....  I was loading realm from Global data...  I stopped that and loaded realm right when i got the data from my rest service...

upon doing that everything started just working correctly, lol...

Comment: Or what you can do is remove the `null` field from the JSON string. Then Realm will just ignore  the field when update it. eg. `{"id" : 1, "subObj":null, "string" : "abc"}` will update the object which `id==1` with `subObj` to `null` and `string` field to `abc`. But `{"id" : 1, "string" : "abc"}` will just update the `string` field to `abc` and ignore the `subObj` field.